# Appcelerator can start Genymotion emulator, but can't install package: "device not found"

Tags: android-emulator, appcelerator, genymotion

On Win10, I have the following installed:

- Appcelerator Studio
- Appcelerator CLI
- Android SDK (ADB enabled)
- Genymotion (free / private license)

I'm using regular Windows Command Prompt to interact with Appcelerator, trying to run a project via a Genymotion emulator (it's the Appcelerator RSS Reader demo project). I've gotten it to the point where `appc run --platform android` will spin up Genymotion and start the appropriate emulator (the only device available according to the Android SDK Virtual Device Manager).

However, as soon as the emulator is ready, Appc tries to install the apk, and fails with this message:

```
[INFO]  Making sure the adb server is running
[INFO]  Installing apk: C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\Rss Reader\build\android\bin\RSS Reader.apk
[ERROR] Failed to install apk on "192.168.128.101:5555"
[ERROR] Error: device not found
```

**If Appc can find the appropriate emulator to start it up, why does installation fail with "device not found"?**

If I immediately open a new console and check the adb connections, I see the specified device as connected:

```
>C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices<br />
List of devices attached
192.168.128.101:5555    device
```

I have tried the following to troubleshoot:

- Made sure SDK and ADB paths were correct
- Made sure Genymotion paths were correct
- Made sure the emulator has the correct API (25) and OS version (7.1.0)

Just a note, when I try to run `appc run --platform android` without the emulator / Genymotion started, it will spin up the emulator perfectly but never recognizes it being "ready", and fails with the following:

```
[INFO]  Waiting for emulator to become ready...
[ERROR] Emulator failed to start in a timely manner
The current timeout is set to 120000 ms
```

If the emulator is already started, it completes as described in the top, with the "device not found" error.

---

Appc info (generated by Appc CLI on "run"):

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
  Version                     = 10.0.14393
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 17037770752

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 6.11.3
  npm Version                 = 3.10.10

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.14

Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 6.2.2.GA
  SDK Path                    = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.2.2.GA
  Target Platform             = android
```

Comment: Apparently this is [an intermittent issue that is not being worked on at this time](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24906)

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
appc run -p android -C "(name of genymotion virtual device)"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is only for Windows Phone devices according to the CLI docs: `-C, --device-id <udid>               the Windows Phone device or emulator udid to launch the app on; only applicable when target is wp-emulator or wp-device`

Comment: Sorry, but I think you're wrong.
In Android build options has -C option too.
`Android Build Options;
-C, --device-id <name>;
Name of the device or emulator to install the application to.`